# Which direction should I draw a force that is $X$ degrees to the horizontal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, classical-mechanics

Left or right? IE "a table that is $20$ meters, fixed at $35$ degrees to the horizontal". 
Would it be like:
/ or \ ??

Comment: Is there no other context to the question? Typically something else could be used to interpret the direction. If there is nothing else to the question then the actual direction is irrelevant due to symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

The typical convention is that positive angles are counterclockwise, i.e. towards the positive $y$ axis. [See wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Positive_and_negative_angles)

Answer (score 0):

As per convention it should be in the counterclockwise direction. So if the angle is acute ($35$ degrees in this case) , it should be inclined like 
**$$\angle$$**